# .NET stackoverflow error on site start-up

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, stack-overflow

Although I know what a stackoverflow exception is, I have one out of the blue and can't work out why.
I've had a web app running fine for a year and tonight after I made a minor change I tried to test it and got a stackoverflow exception on the Setting.Designer.Cs file, the error being on the return line below.
I tried debugging but it seems to happen as soon as the site fires up, does anyone have any ideas or anything I should try?

thanks

```
public string DB_xxx_xxConnectionString
{
    get {
            return ((string)(this["DB_xxx_xxConnectionString"]));
        }
}
```

Comment: Quite possibly something prior to this call that caused the stack to grow out of control. This just happened to be the one that sent it over. If you can breakpoint here and see what the call stack looks like prior to this you might find the problem.

Comment: did just that and found it - I was initializing too many things throughout the site, which to be honest I did not know would be a problem. Have a way round it now so all good, thanks